# System.out.println in java - Is out initialized in a native method?

Tags: java

I just wanted to know if the `out` variable in `System.out.println()` is initialized in the static block of the `System` class. The `out` field is declared as a final static variable, which equals null (`public final static PrintStream out = null;`) . Since out is pointing to null, I assume it is being pointed to the `PrintStream` object somewhere. But I can't see the code except a native method called `registerNatives()`. Is it being pointed to in a native method? Why is it being done that way (any performance advantage)? 
Also, the documentation for the `out` variable in `System` says:

> The "standard" output stream. This stream is already open and ready to accept output data. Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user."

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing that `out` just varies from a platform to an other. So it wouldn't make any sense to initialize it in Java. Each platform must then create the object according to their respective architecture

Comment: It's actually well known that the JVM plays special tricks with `out`, for example if `out` is `final` how can you call `System.setOut()` on it?  The answer is it isn't really final, and the JVM has been hard coded to ignore the modifier (although the assignment is still thread safe -- that's also hard coded).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Reference JDK 1.8***

The out registration flow

`Java Virtual Machine (JVM)` invokes

`private static void initializeSystemClass()` at `line-1155`

The function call

`setOut0(newPrintStream(fdOut, props.getProperty("sun.stdout.encoding")))` at `line-1192` invokes

actual `native method` defined

`private static native void setOut0(PrintStream out);` at `line-258`;

> then `setOut0` then initializes the `out` class memeber.

Comment: Note : library reference `jdk 1.8`